# LinqKit and async in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, predicatebuilder, linqkit

I am getting the following error when using the predicate builder with Entity Framework Core.

> The source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncEnumerable. Only
>   sources that implement IAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity
>   Framework asynchronous operations.

This is the code -

```
 List<Member> results = await _context.Members.AsExpandable().Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
```

This the exact version of EF I'm using

```
  <package id="EntityFramework.Core" version="7.0.0-rc1-final" targetFramework="net451" />
```

Answer (score 8):

This is supported in a different Nuget package than normal LinqKit.

See: https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/

(for non-Core see https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit.EntityFramework)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it looks like very new package, don't think I want to use it on a production system just yet.

Comment: @Bryan AFAIK, the existing LinqKit maintainers just split their packages... you can use an older version of LinqKit package if it makes you feel better: https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/1.1.3.1

Comment: Yes the LinqKit.EntityFramework is the old LinqKit and the reason was that people wanted the EF dependency away.